# How to find the domain of $\ln(\sqrt{1-x})$?

Tags: calculus

How to find the domain of $\ln(\sqrt{1-x})$?

I know that the domain of $\ln(x)$ should be larger than $0$,
and I know that the domain of $\sqrt{1-x}$ should be larger than or equal to $1$,
but how do I find the domain of the composition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect you have the right idea, but you misstated the domain of $\sqrt{1-x}$.  Try a value "larger than or equal to 1" and you'll see the point.

Comment: That's true, I miscalculated the domain of sqrt(1-x) as it should be x < 1. Does this mean that the domain of the composition is 0 < x < 1 ?

Comment: Well, you definitely want to avoid $x=1$ since the logarithm won't take the resulting zero square root.  However check the other endpoint...

Comment: Thanks I already understand it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\ln\sqrt{1-x}$ is defined if and only if $\sqrt{1-x}$ is defined
and satisfies $\sqrt{1-x}>0$.

$\sqrt{1-x}$ is defined and satisfies $\sqrt{1-x}>0$ if and only
if $1-x>0$ or equivalently $x<1$.

Comment: You are very welcome.